# SQL Theory - Group by all attributes of relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Theoretical question. Say we have relation `R(A,B,C)`.
For fun, let's say that this is the Relation Table

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
1   2   2
1   2   3
1   1   1
```

And we execute the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM R
GROUP BY A,B,C;
```

What would the result be?

Comment: Try it first! You will know!

Comment: If you have only three columns, it will remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is SQL Server 2008 (or similar compliance).

Input:

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
1   2   2
1   2   3
1   1   1
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM R
GROUP BY A,B,C;
```

Output

```
A   B   C
1   1   1
1   2   2
1   2   3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2bcd/1/0

Comment: That result isn't specific to SQL Server. This is how the SQL standard defines the GROUP BY behavior. Any DBMS that returns something different (apart from the order of the rows) is seriously broken (in my opinion)